# How to get form field in handler Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have got some input fields in Flask form:

```
<input type="time" name="time[0]"/>
<input type="time" name="time[1]"/>
<input type="time" name="time[2]"/>
```

I tried to get these input values like:

```
values = request.args.get('time')

for v in values
    print v
```

But it does not work for me.

Also as I know correct I can not use `<input type="time" name="time[]"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal flask server I have,

```
from flask import request
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    values = request.args.getlist('time[]')
    print values
    values = request.form.getlist('time[]')
    print values

    if request.method == 'POST':
      # The logic may goes here...
      return render_template('test.html')
    else:
        return render_template('test.html')
```

HTML template(test.html) is,

```
<form method="get">
<input type="time" name="time[]"/>
<input type="time" name="time[]"/>
<input type="time" name="time[]"/>
<input type="time" name="time[]"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted after the times are entered, below is how I'm able to collect the data.

```
values = request.args.getlist('time[]')
print values # Printed [u'17:06', u'09:00', u'22:01', u'07:08']
```

When the form's method is changed to "post", I'm getting the data with,

```
values = request.form.getlist('time[]')
print values # Printed [u'17:06', u'09:00', u'22:01', u'07:08']
```

Hopefully, should work! Let me know if my snippets have been deviating from your requirement.

Comment: I tried this way, it returns me `None`

Comment: Do you suggest this for: `name="time[1]"`?

Comment: Can you complement your answer with loop for `values`?

Comment: I would suggest     "name=time[]", without indices.. and I've updated my answer by changing argument to **getlist**

Comment: İt does not work too, check please before posting